# htmlspecialchars text

Tags: php

I have created an article comment for my user to post comment. I also have a function that automatically creates link if url is detected in the message. However now I am puzzled as to how do I convert text using htmlspecialchars and at the same time creates the link together without "authoring the URL"?

For example:

```
$message = 'This is a message with a url http://www.stackoverflow.com?id=1&get=1';
makeLink( htmlspecialchars( $message ) )

// I will get "This is a message with a url http://www.stackoverflow.com?id=1&amp;get=1" 
// Notice the ampersand became &amp; How do I prevent this?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either fold it back to regular text using `html_entity_decode()` or use RegEx or regular text replacement to make `&amp;` turn back to `&`.

Comment: Hi Hen: html_entity_decode( makeLink( htmlspecialchars( $message ) ) seems not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use html_entity_decode($a)

i think your issue will be solved by use of this

Comment: Thanks Sha, do you have any idea on how do I do this?

Comment: html_entity_decode( makeLink( htmlspecialchars( $message ) )
seems not possible?

Comment: I Create below example after running on browser do view source their you find the difference between two statement in one &amp; and after applying html_entity_decode it gives output as you want -----------------------------------------------------------------


    $message = 'This is a message with a url http://www.stackoverflow.com?id=1&get=1'
    echo $a = htmlentities($message);
    echo "<hr>";
    echo $b = html_entity_decode($a);
    exit;
   -----------------------------------------------------------------